# No sound on Skype 4.3 lubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, lubuntu, skype, alsa

New to Linux just installed Skype 4.3 on Lubuntu 14.4.

There is no sound when I call Skype Echo, totally silent.

I have sound if I play music or video files.

I notice sound driver is Version k1313.0-34-generic. Earlier today the Software Updater said it could not read "Linux Image 3.13.0-34generic as could not read 'Dev/SDC'

Just wondering if two problems are connected.

Software Updater now says system is up to date

Comment: Does Skype have a valid audio out? You can check it in Skype options.

Answer (score 1):

Skype 4.3 can only use `pulseaudio` sound daemon to output sound. As I understand you have no sound *at all* in skype so I guess you either don't have pulseaudio or you don't have it running.

I would recommend you to install `pavucontrol` and try to figure out if you have sound input/output working.

So the solution:

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol; pavucontrol`